# Google Now Launcher still exists inside launcher settings

Tags: launcher, lineageos, redmi-1s

I have used Google Now Launcher on my Redmi 1S that runs Lineage OS 14.1. And, now I am using Nova Launcher as home app(launcher). I have uninstalled Google Now Launcher, and also, its not present in app list. But, it is still listed in launcher settings (Settings->Apps->Configure Apps (settings icon)->Home App). I have tried to clear cache from recovery, but have no result. I have uninstalled Nova launcher, but still it shows Google Now launcher, and Trebuchet to set as Home App. May be it got saved somewhere permanently, otherwise I have tried to make Google Now launcher as system app, it may be happened due to this. How to solve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed Google now launcher from play store. And the default launcher is Trebuchet which is similar to that of Google now launcher.

The device is rooted, and I tried to make Google now launcher as a system app. For, that I changed permissions of app using ES file explorer.

This may got saved, and that's why it not removed from default app list.

I performed a fresh install of lineage os which solved from this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Did you install Google Now Launcher as part of a Google Apps package? If this is the case, Google Now Launcher will be installed as a /system app. Therefore, you'll have to remove it manually using a file manager or recovery mode.

Comment: Google Now launcher installed from playstore